# Loshon hora and Torah lectures

Tags: sources-mekorot, loshon-hara, chofetz-chaim

Where in hilchos loshon hora, does the chofetz chaim say that ridiculing Torah lectures is a form of loshon hora?

Comment: Its one of his most used examples

Comment: What gave you the idea that he says this somewhere therein? Why do you want to find it?

Comment: In Guard Your Tongue by Rabbi Zelig Pliskin, page 39.

Comment: Wouldn't this not apply then if the lecture was so bad that it isn't even considered Torah? (which is probably why people are making fun of it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chafetz Chayim, Lashon ha-Ra, 2:12, see [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47570&st=&pgnum=147).